# Seas Without Water

Tags: riddle

I have seas without water

I have forests without wood

I have deserts without sand

I have houses with no brick

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is... a shrubbery! .... ....

> Or a map

Reasoning:

> Maps have seas, forests, deserts, or houses marked, but as they are, well, maps, they don't actually have water, wood, sand or bricks.

Comment: First you must find... another shrubbery! Then, when you have found the shrubbery, you must place it here, beside this shrubbery, only slightly higher so you get a two layer effect with a little path running down the middle. Then, you must cut down the mightiest tree in the forrest... with... a herring!

Comment: @bgmCoder, Ni !