# I have maps but am not a map

Tags: riddle

[I have forests with no wood](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9273/seas-without-water),

rope that will not bind,

bags that hold no food,

and masks you cannot hide behind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a

> programming language

I have maps but am not a map

> A programming language can have maps that contain key-value pairs.

I have forests with no wood,

> A programming language can have tree data structures.  Multiple trees could be called a "forest".

rope that will not bind,

> A programming language can have a rope data structure that contains strings.

bags that hold no food,

> A programming language can have a bag data structure that contains other objects.

and masks you cannot hide behind.

> A programming language has bit masks.

Comment: I figured this wouldn't take long on stackexchange :)

Comment: Rats! I thought programming languages had binding but no ropes. +1 for teaching me a new data structure with a puzzle :)